# What happened to elfsign and elfverify?

Tags: security, checksum, elf, signature, verification

In *"Uninformed Research -- informative information for the uninformed."* 2003 mentions a tool called `elfsign` and `elfverify`. This is a tool to checksum and sign an ELF binary.

I can't find that tool in Debian. Does it still exist and is it maintained?

Comment: If your goal is just to guarantee integrity when running executables, consider using IMA (Integrity Measurement Architecture) for Linux, which does this at the kernel level by using extended attributes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That tool seems to be written by the same author of the paper `skape (mmiller@hick.org)`. It's withheld from [Debian for licensing reasons -- currently being under "The Clarified Artistic License".](https://lists.debian.org/debian-legal/2004/05/msg00169.html)

The code can be found on his site,

- http://www.hick.org/code/skape/elfsign/

Comment: Other tools purportedly for this purpose include `signelf` and `elfpgp`.  I suspect that there is more than one Q&A to be had on this subject.  (-: